# Facebook page API - page feed (any difference between using auth_token and not using it?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was accessing different pages on Facebook, and I was using the `auth_token` parameter obtained from the Graph API, after the user enabled my application's access in there.

Now, I tried to access the feed data via the API without the `auth_token`, and it seems I get the same thing. Is there any use for the auth_token when fetching a page's feed?

Here's how an authenticated request looks like: https://graph.facebook.com/172697656074654/feed

It seems there is no difference between the data I get when authenticating, and the data I get when not being authenticated.

My question would be:
- do you think that it is possible that some feed items won't show up when non-authenticated?

This is the "page" API documentation, any input on this would be great, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a big difference, in Facebook there are fields that are `Publicly accessible` and `Available to everyone on Facebook` among a lot of other permissions.

A *viewer* can be a:

- ***An authenticated user*** - Logged-in Facebook user
- ***A non-authenticated user*** - logged-out Facebook user (or not a Facebook user at all)

Facebook deals with each case (*viewer*) depending on each field. **BUT** still the above doesn't apply everytime.
For example while `Available to everyone on Facebook` means a logged-in user can view that specific field of the object we are browsing, this is **not** always true. As the *object owner* may have strict privacy setting that will override the *general* permission. And hence that field is no longer *visible*.

To better understand this:

- Go to the [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object.
- Click on the example provided, check the comments and the count returned.
- Now remove the `access_token` parameter and check again. You'll notice that the count is now less than the previous link!